# Quantum Walk Study Resource for Non-regular Graph

Tags: quantum-walks

Does anyone know any good resource where I can study about how quantum walk is performed on non-regular graph?
Most of the papers I read, talks about only quantum walk on regular graphs containing cycles. For non-regular graph as each node have different degree, the dimensions of coin operator needs to keep changing. No resource talks about this.
If anyone have any source, it will be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Some important references could be the following: [Quantum Walks On Graphs](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0012090),

[Quantum walks: a comprehensive review](https://arxiv.org/abs/1201.4780),

[Quantum random walks - an introductory overview](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0303081).